# How can I create a crop box for camera app on an Android device?

Tags: java, android

iI want to create a app to crop a part of picture exactly after taking a picture in camera app, like this image:

[image: Preview of photo cropping app]

But I don't know how.

Comment: Take a look this library: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to configure camera preview with Android Camera(2) API. ([example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) for more details).

Next put your preview surface in FrameLayout and add view over preview surface to draw crop rectangle.

Crop image using, for example, `Bitmap.createBitmap(source, left, top, width, height)`. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). (If you configured camera for `jpg` output you should first [decode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) captured image.)